# Why this GET request is not working?

Tags: node.js, express, codeanywhere

enter image description here

[I am doing all this on codeanywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEXLy.png)

Comment: Post all code directly here as text, and give more detail about the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question adding that code here, if that link changes or break, your question gets irrelevant. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I can never understand how taking and uploading a screenshot is easier than copying and pasting code that is already open in an editor.

Comment: Also, your first link is hidden and people can't see what your problem is.

Comment: And then to solve your problem: Just look up what express is used for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Unless..

Make sure you `npm install express`

Since your file is named `app.js` make sure in your `package.json` file it reads something like this.

Make sure main says `app.js` not `index.js` or `server.js`

```
{
  "name": "stack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  }
}
```

This will give you an err if something breaks.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hi there");
})


app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}`);
  }
});
```